# TABLE - How To Get Spaces in Between TDs

Tags: html, css

I create a table having circles in TDs.  Please take a look at this sample at [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/1154/)

I want to get spaces in between these circles by trying to add more style in CSS

```
border-spacing: 10px;
border-collapse: separate;
```

but somehow it doesn't show up spaces.  Please help!

Below is the code:

```css
table tr td{
    background-color:green;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-spacing` and `border-collapse` should be set on the `table`, not the `td`.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

table tr td{
    background-color:green;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```